# how to test if there is any word matched the string in Python

Tags: python, string, split, phrase

I want to write a python program to test if there are any phrase can match the string using python.

```
string ='I love my travel all over the world'
list =['I love','my travel','all over the world']
```

So I want to text if there are any one of list can match that string that can print 'I love' or 'my travel','all over the world'.

```
any(x in string for x in list)
```

Or I need to use text mining to solve the problem?

Comment: This works, what is the problem?

Comment: @TimCastelijns when I run the previous code,the code can run,but I could not see any results in the python shell

Comment: The result will be a boolean, what are you hoping to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
if any(x in string for x in word_list)
    print x
```

Because the `any` function iterates through the entire string/list, discards the `x` variable, and then simply returns a Boolean (`True` or `False`).

You can however, just break apart your `any` function so that you can get your desired output.

```
string ='I love traveling all over the world'
word_list =['I love','traveling','all over the world']

for x in word_list:
    if x in string:
        print x
```

This will output:

```
>>>
I love
traveling
all over the world
>>>
```

**Update using *`string.split()`* :**

```
string =['I', 'love','traveling','all', 'over', 'the', 'world']
word_list =['I love','traveling','all over the world']
count=0
for x in word_list:
    for y in x.split():
        if y in string:
            count+=1
            if count==len(x.split()) and (' ' in x) == True:
                print x
    count=0
```

This will output:

```
>>> 
I love
all over the world
>>>
```

Comment: one further question,if I use .split() to split the string into ['I',' love',' traveling', 'all', 'over', 'the', 'world'],does word_list can still try to match the word_list above?

Comment: @user3849475 Yes it will work :) I added an edit to my answer for that case.

Comment: thx! I mean if I split the string into lstring =['I',' love',' traveling', 'all', 'over', 'the', 'world'],can word_list =['I love','traveling','all over the world'] still match the lstring? Or to let lstring try to match the word_list to find if there is any match ?

Comment: it wouldn't give you an error but it would only find its exact matches. In that case it would only output "travelling" because thats the only word that can be exactly matched in both lists

Comment: For example:if lstring =['I',' love',' my travel', 'all', 'over', 'the', 'world'],word_list =['I love','traveling','all over the world'] so ideal print would be 'I love',and 'all over the world'.

Comment: @user3849475 do you have to use `string.split()`?

Comment: yes.I use string.split() to get the lstring=['I',' love',' traveling', 'all', 'over', 'the', 'world'].So now I don't consider the ordinal of lstring,if any words on lstring can full match word_list2 =[''all over the world',"all the world"] that the ideal print is 'all over the world ',and 'all the world'.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is probably the best to use in this given scenario.  You could encapsulate it as a function if you wanted.

```
def list_in_string(slist, string):
    return any(x in string for x in slist_list)
```

Comment: once I run the code,I could not see any result in my IDLE

Answer (score 0):

If you want a True or False returned, you can definitely use `any()`, for example:

```
>>> string = 'I love my travel all over the world'
>>> list_string =['I love',
          'my travel',
          'all over the world',
          'Something something',
          'blah']
>>> any(x for x in list_string if x in string)
True
>>>
```

Otherwise, you could do some simple list comprehension:

```
>>> string ='I love my travel all over the world'
>>> list_string =['I love',
          'my travel',
          'all over the world',
          'Something something',
          'blah']
>>> [x for x in list_string if x in string]
['I love', 'my travel', 'all over the world']
>>>
```

Depending on what you want returned, both of these work perfectly.

You could also probably use regular expression, but it's a little overkill for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, one may mention the `find` method:

```
_string ='I love my travel all over the world'
_list =['I love','my travel','all over the world','spam','python']

for i in range(len(_list)):
    if _string.find(_list[i]) > -1:
        print _list[i]
```

Which outputs:

```
I love
my travel
all over the world
```

Note: this solution is not as elegant as the `in` usage mentioned, but may be useful if the *position* of the found substring is needed.